# How can an API application be vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, csrf

I have a Web API application and have configured SSL for it.

Our authentication mechanism is via the header. Each request will have to contain a pair of keys that we will validate them against our database. We're not using Forms/Basic or Digect authentication.

I'm just wondering do we have to do anything with regard to the Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) issue? is it applicable in this case?

I thought because we're not using the cookies so it should be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, forcing another user to do a request only has an advantage for an attacker if that user's browser automatically pushes some credential that the attacker does not have. That can be:

- auth cookie
- HTTP Authentication (Basic/Digest/Windows Auth)
- TLS session ID (in HTTPS)
- implicit authorisation from IP address or network location (eg intranet site)

If you are not relying on any such credential, then there is no CSRF attack to defend against.

Comment: thanks yeah, we're not relying on any cookies, sessions or http authentications. However, we do have IP address restrictions on the server which is just an additional layer on top of our header tokens security.

Comment: OK, so in that case your lack of CSRF protection does make your IP address restriction much less effective. An attacker would still have to have a keypair to populate the credential header, but now they can do so from outside the authorised IP range, by hijacking a browser inside that range (using `XMLHttpRequest` from another site so that a header can be set). You need CSRF protection if you are not confident that the credential check is enough in itself and you want to ensure the IP restriction is enforced.